# Vue.js CSS bundle precedence (?)

Tags: css, vuejs2, vue-cli

I have a weird issue with Vue.js CLI production bundling where I cannot quite pinpoint the root cause and I appreciate some help.

I have a Vue CLI 3 application with the following (relevant extract) in my main.js:

```
// Bootstrap
import "@/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

// Toastr
import Toastr from "vue-toastr";
import "vue-toastr/dist/vue-toastr.css";
Vue.use(Toastr, {
  defaultPosition: "toast-bottom-right"
});
```

**Running this in my dev environment (`npm run serve`) CSS works fine.**

When I run this after the production complilation (`npm run build`) some classes... are not applied and I cannot reason why. Given that the only difference I can see is the bundling process, I'm incline to look for an issue in that direction.

I customized the bundling as follow (relevant extract) in my vue.config.js:

```
cacheGroups: {
  icons: {
    name: "icons",
    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](@fortawesome)[\\/]/,
    chunks: "all",
    priority: 3
  },
  vendors: {
     name: "vendors",
     test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
     chunks: "all",
     priority: 1
  }
}
```

And, as result, my CSS bundled are correctly created as follows:

- a **vendor** chunk that includes the Toaster CSS.
  This includes a 'toaster' class and a 'toaster-info' class (this latest has just a background-color)
- a **app** chink that include my custom built bootstrap CSS.
  As much as the bootstrap files are in the node_modules folder and, as such, they should go in the previous chink, they get in here because I'm compiling them as import in a the SASS file above that actually comes from by code.
  This includes a 'toaster' class again.

Now, what I can see is that:

- both chunks appear to be loaded by the browser
- the markup correctly uses the 'toastr toastr-info'
- only the 'toaster' class from app (bootstrap) is applied
- *the 'toaster' and 'toaster-info' class are totally ignored by the browser and the background color from 'toaster-info' is not applied*

I tested this with several browsers to exclude any specific browser weirdness.
Browser computed styles shows that the classes are "excluded" for some reason I don't understand (with "excluded" meaning are in the style tree but strikethrough).

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: In your dev console, when inspecting the elements you can use the _"Computed"_ tab to see which styles _are_ being applied and where they are defined.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring above as "browser debugging". Class shows as "strikethrough" but I don't know why.

Comment: Could you please post some screenshots from the browser console? If styles are being overridden (typically what causes them to be shown strikethru), you need to find what **is** being applied instead

Comment: Sure, this is what I can see: [capture](http://blog.echopod.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Capture.png)

Comment: Right, so that's saying because `.toast` has a higher specificity than the others, it is the one that is applied. It's probably higher because `app.css` is defined after `vendor.css`. Why are you defining `.toast` in your app style?

Comment: Both CSS define the `.toast`: `app` from my custom bootstrap and `vendor` from the actual toastr component - Given they are defined the same, I expected them to combine (?). The one from bootstrap is actually redundant but I cannot exclude that from compilation. Neither I can control which bundle gets loaded first (vue controls that?). And `toast-info` from `vendor` is not computed at all (?).

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a CSS problem.

Since your app and vendor CSS defines a `.toast` class style, whatever is loaded last is given the highest specificity.

I'm assuming all you're trying to do is change the default `.toast` background colour to white (instead of black) but you want to leave the more specific classes like `.toast-info`, `.toast-success`, etc as they are.

To do so (without altering the vendor files), you can change your `.toast` definition to...

```
.toast:not(.toast-info),
.toast:not(.toast-success),
.toast:not(.toast-warning),
.toast:not(.toast-error) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
}
```

If you're using a pre-processor like Sass (which I think you are), this can be written more succinctly.

---

Ideally, the vendor files should have defined their styles like...

```css
.toast {
  background-color: #030303;
}
.toast.toast-success {
  background-color: #51a351;
}
```

which would give the "*info"*, *"success"*, etc styles a higher specificity than the `.toast` class but it doesn't look like they do. Perhaps you could create a pull-request

Comment: I see about the precedence. Actually, both classes come from vendor files so I cannot change them (although I'm not really using the one from bootstrap). I still do not understand this: the `toast-success` is defined without chaining `.toast-success { background-color: #something }` - will that background color be dropped because is defined among others in the class that takes precedence (that white you're seeing)?

Comment: @Edoardo Both `.toast` and `.toast-success` have the same precedence / specificity and both are assigned to your HTML element so whatever one defines `background-color` last is the one that wins. That's why I added that note about what the vendor files should **ideally** do.

Comment: @Edoardo I assumed that the white `.toast` was defined in `@/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss` since it appears in your _app_ chunk and not the _vendor_ chunk. If it isn't, it must be defined somewhere else in your app files.

Comment: first of all, thank you for taking time to answer to me. You are correct, the white comes from there. Problem is that the toaster CSS gets in the `vendor` bundle because is imported directly from `node_modules`. Bootstrap, ideally should get there as well but since the importing SCSS is in my code, gets in the `app' bundle, loaded later and deprioritized.

Comment: I found a way to redirect the content of the two bundles in one. Now both definition of the same class (and the `toast-success`) are in the same file... and still it doesn't work no matter the order in which they are built.

Comment: In the end, I fiddled enough with the bundles and got it working, although I still do not understand why... :)